# PHP Retrieve Object with Nested Collection and Use it to the PHP Code

Tags: php, symfony

I have this kind of request body:

```
{
   "title": "foo",
   "colors": [{
       "name": "green"
   }, {
       "name": "red"
   },{
       "name": "pink"
   }]
}
```

This is a sample request body being sent from POSTMAN. I have a method on my PHP backend that gets the request body. So far, here's what I have,

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;

public function test (Request $request)
{
    $data = json_decode($request->getContent(), false);
    
    dd($data->title); // foo
}
```

It works on a single object, but when I try `$data->colors` the result is different. Like this: `a:1:{i:0;s:2:"green";i:1;s:2:"red";i:2;s:2:"pink"}`

What I expected to be a string result is something like this: `[{"name": "green"}, ... ]`

Basically, what I need is to get the proper collection string. Any help?

Comment: I'm not familiar with symfony or how `dd` (which I do understand is primarily a debugging tool) formats things by default, but it looks like it's serialising the colors array. If you want to see it logged in JSON format, you may need to manually json-encode it again before logging it (e.g. dd(json_encode($dd->colors));` - give that a try.

Comment: Look at https://3v4l.org/UDh4S to see an example of serialised output (for background info and illustrate my comment), see also https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php

Comment: `dd` is a debugging helper that apparently uses `serialize()` to encode the data structure as string. Use `print_r()` to see a simpler representation of the data. `print_r()` is also a developer helper, do not use it to produce output for production. As an advice, pass `true` as the second argument to [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) to ask it to create associative arrays, not objects. The arrays are more versatile that the blunt `stdClass`.

Comment: I tried passing the argument with `true` but when I save it to the database, it doesn't save the one that I expected like: `[{"name": "green" ... ]` but instead it displays a text that includes the number of array

Comment: Why are you expecting to save json to the database anyway? Don't you have a normalised data structure to place all this into? Your original question was about debug output/visualisation formats, not data storage

Comment: @JokerBench Regarding storage, that's just how Doctrine stores it when you use the `array` type. If you set it to `json` instead then it should look like `[{"name": "green" ... ]`

Answer (score 1):

Pass `true` as the second argument of [`json_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode) to ask it to produce associative arrays (instead of PHP objects) from the objects that it finds in the input JSON. The PHP arrays are more versatile than the objects and their processing is easier.

```php
$input = '{
   "title": "foo",
   "colors": [{
       "name": "green"
   }, {
       "name": "red"
   },{
       "name": "pink"
   }]
}';

$data = json_decode($input, true);

foreach ($data['colors'] as $color) {
  echo("${color['name']}\n");
}
```

The output is:

```
green
red
pink
```

See it [online](https://3v4l.org/n0YIM).

If you need to get the value of the `colors` property as JSON then you can just encode it as JSON using `json_encode($data['colors'])`.